# Outlook pop deleting server messages regardless of age

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pop3

I am using Outlook 2016
I have set up my POP to always keep mails on server, but to delete a copy older than 14 days.
This has been my standard config for many moons, and works great.
Now, my outlook jut always delete from server regardless of age meaning that either. This happens after everytime I check for messages

- Keep on server setting is being ignored, or
- The age is being ignored (and it thinks everything is older than 14 days)

What could be causing this?

Other interesting clues
 - If I turn off the "delete older than" rule, I get duplicates of mails every time I check email
 - This happens on 2 different email accounts (hosted at 2 completely different companies, so that rules out a server issue)

I don't want to use Imap, because I have limited server space so I want emails so slowly wittle away from my server (but 2 weeks is a nice storage sweet spot for me so other devices that use imap have a decent history)

Only 1 device uses pop. and I have proven that my outlook is the culprit (turn off and mails dont delete)

So my questiosn are, has anyone ever solved this before? and how would I even begin troubleshooting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've run into this bug:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3145116

At this point, Microsoft doesn't have a fix:

> Microsoft is researching this problem and will post more information in this article when the information becomes available.